# Moment of Inertia of a wire

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A wire has the shape of the circle x^2 + y^2 = a^2. Determine its
mass and moment of inertia about a diameter if the density at (x, y)
is |x| + |y|.

I found that the mass is 4a^2 (don't know if it's the answer), but couldn't find the moment of inertia, wich answer is 4a^4.

Thanks!

Comment: Show us your work so far so that we can see where you're going wrong or getting stuck.

Comment: Is the moment of inertia invariant with the argument (angle) of the diameter?  That's kind of interesting.

Comment: @brian I'd expect so because of symmetry. Half of the mass is on either side of the diameter and it's distributed similarly.

Comment: First, I parametrized the curve as g(t)=(a*cost, a*sint), then I separeted in 4 cases, when the density(f(x,y)) is x+y, -x+y, -x-y, x-y. As ||g(t)||=a, I integrated f(g(t))*||g(t)|| in these four cases. The first one from 0 to pi/2, the second one from pi/2 to pi, the third one from pi to 3pi/2 and the last one from 3pi/2 to 2pi. Then I summed all of them and got that the total mass is equal to 4a^2.

Comment: @amd: It's not implausible to me, but consider (for instance) that if one uses the axis $y = x$, then the densest parts of the ring are at the "poles" and at the "equator", whereas if one uses $x = 0$ as the axis, the densest parts are at the "mid-latitudes".  It was not immediately obvious to me that this makes no difference.

Comment: @BrianTung: Am I thinking right to determine the mass of the wire?

Comment: @brian Imagine the mass concentrated at the “equator" and “poles" relative to some diameter. As you rotate away from this axis by some angle $\theta$, the mass at the equator moves inward to a distance of $r \cos\theta$ while the polar mass moves out to $r \sin\theta$. Square and add these distances and you have $r^2$, so the two masses still make the same contribution to the moment of inertia.

Comment: @amd: Could you determine the mass?

Comment: Your process for computing the mass looks correct, but you lost a factor of 2 somewhere in the computation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an element of circle whose mass is $$\rho a\delta\theta$$ and therefore whose moment of inertia about an axis perpendicular to the plane of the circle and through the centre of the circle is $$\rho a^3 \delta\theta$$
$$=a^3(|x|+|y|)\delta\theta$$
Therefore the moment of inertia about this axis is $$a^3\int_0^{2\pi}(|x|+|y|)d\theta$$
$$=a^4\int_0^{2\pi}(|\cos\theta|+|\sin\theta|)d\theta$$
$$=8a^4$$
Then, applying symmetry in $x$ and $y$ and the perpendicular axes theorem, the required moment of inertia about the diameter is $$\frac 12 8a^4=4a^4$$

Answer (score 1):

The mass of the wire is given by the absolute line integral of the density: $$\begin{align}
M=\int_C\rho\;ds=\int_C\left|x\right|+\left|y\right|ds&=\int_0^{2\pi}(\left|a\cos\theta\right|+\left|a\sin\theta\right|)\;a\;d\theta \\
&=a^2\int_0^{2\pi}\left|\cos\theta\right|+\left|\sin\theta\right|d\theta=8a^2.\end{align}$$

The moment of inertia about a diameter can be found by taking advantage of a symmetry.

Consider two small sections $\rho\;ds$ of the wire, one at an angle of $\theta$ from the chosen diameter, the other at $\theta+\frac\pi 2$. Since $\rho(\theta)=\rho(\theta+\frac\pi 2)$, their net contribution to the moment of inertia is $(a\cos\theta)^2\rho(\theta)\;ds+(a\sin\theta)^2\rho(\theta)\;ds=a^2\rho(\theta)\;ds$, i.e., the same as if half of their combined mass were concentrated at the “equator.” Therefore, the total moment of inertia about a diameter of the wire loop is $$I_\text{diam.}=\frac12Ma^2=4a^4.$$One can, of course, get the same result by computing $I_x=\int_C\rho y^2 ds$ directly and making a similar appeal to symmetry to show that this equals the moment of inertia about any other diameter.